# Confused About Step in Proof of Divergence of $\sum \frac{1}{p}$

Tags: self-learning, analytic-number-theory, proof-explanation

I was going through the number theory text by Ireland and Rosen, and was following the proof of the divergence of the sum of reciprocal primes. But I came across a step unclear to me.

The proof so far: https://imgur.com/XbPkBak&JeMOqku

The step itself: https://imgur.com/XbPkBak&JeMOqku#1

I cannot see the equality between the two sides. Help is appreciated.

Comment: They are using the taylor series for $\log(1-x)$.

Comment: Isn't it just Taylor series expansion?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the expansion, thanks.

Comment: How does the proof finish?

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Comment: Nevermind... it must finish by showing all the terms except $\sum 1/p$ in $\lambda(n)$ are finite, specifically bounded by something close to $\sum 1/k^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user3663006 , the logarithmic power series is

$$\log(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n\;\;,\;\;|x|<1$$

and from here

$$\log(1-p^{-s})=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{p^{-ns}}n\;\ldots$$

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for clearing that up.